# How to edit text within a modal in Kentico CMS

Tags: html, modal-dialog, kentico

On a page, there are buttons which when clicked open a modal popup. We are using Kentico CMS, and in the editing pages when I click the button it only allows me to change the button text. I cannot find any way to get access to the text within the modal other than via the source html. This is fine for me, but the site I am helping with is mainly going to be edited by someone with zero html knowledge, and 95% of the editing will be the text shown on the modal.

Is there a way with Kentico CMS to edit the text on a modal without going into the source code?

Comment: More information is needed. Which version of Kentico are you using? Is it MVC or Portal mode? When you say you are editing a modal, is this a custom modal that has been built by a developer in Kentico?

Comment: Hi, It is a custom Modal I have made myself using Bootstrap. Speaking to the support team at kentico it seems that there is no way of editing the modal content without editing the source html. I have found another piece of software which is installed locally and is much more powerful than kentico so we are going to use this and just copy the html into the source in Kentico.

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken to the support team at Kentico and it appears that editing custom-designed Modals is not possible in the Kentico CMS other than by editing the source code.